# Sorting files by "line content" frequency

Tags: bash, sorting

Imagine that there are 3 text files.

1.txt:

```
a
b
c
```

2.txt:

```
f
c
d
```

3.txt:

```
b
c
f
```

How do I sort them by frequency of each **"line content"**? (In case of collisions alphabetically)

Result:

```
c
b
f
a
d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sort` and `uniq` to sort the lines by frequencies.

```
sort *.txt | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]* //'
```

The second `sort` uses the secondary `-k2` to sort the lines of the same frequency alphabetically. The final `sed` just removes the frequencies.

Comment: Didn't test yet, but gonna accept and upvote for that alphabetical part included. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I've tested it before posting :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can sort in descending order of frequency using sort and uniq:

```
$ sort *.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn
      3 c
      2 f
      2 b
      1 d
      1 a
```

If you want to remove the count:

```
$ sort *.txt | uniq -c | sort -rn | sed 's/[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]*[[:space:]]//'
c
f
b
d
a
```

Note that two calls to `sort` are required.  The first is because `uniq -c` requires sorted input.  The second is needed to sort the lines into descending numerical order by count (frequency).